# Matlab Distributed Server parfor can't find mex opencv files

Tags: matlab, opencv, parallel-processing, private, parfor

everyone!

I'm trying to parallelize an algorithm that uses mex files  from mexopencv (**KNearest.m, KNearest_.mexw32**).

The program is based vlfeat (vlsift.mex32) + mexopencv (KNearest.m and KNearest_.mexw32).I classify descriptors obtained from images.

All the code is located on the fileshare

```
\\ LAB-07 \ untitled \ DISTRIB \ (this is the program code) 
\\ LAB-07 \ untitled \ + cv (mexopencv)
```

When I run the program with **matlabpool close** everything works well.

Then I make matlabpool open (2 computers on 2 cores each. ultimately 4 worker, but now I use for testing only 2 workers on the computer and run the program which)
PathDependencises from fileshare -> **\LAB-07\untitled\DISTRIB\ , \LAB-07\untitled+cv**

Before parfor loop I train classifier on the local machine

```
classifiers = cv.KNearest
classifiers.train(Descriptors',Labels','MaxK',1)
```

Then run parfor

```
descr=vlsift(img);
PredictClasses = classifiers.predict(descr');
```

Error

```
Error in ==> KNearest>KNearest.find_nearest at 173
Invalid MEX-file '\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\private\KNearest_.mexw32': 
The specified module could not be found.
```

That is **KNearest.m** finds, but no **KNearest_.mexw32**. Because KNearest_.mexw32 located in private folder, I changed the code KNearest.m (everywhere where it appeal KNearest_ () changed to cv.KNearest_ (). Example: this.id = сv.KNearest_ ()) and placed in a folder with KNearest_.mexw32 KNearest.m. As a result, get the same error

Immediately after matlabpool open file search on workers

```
pctRunOnAll which ('KNearest.m')
'KNearest.m' not found.
'KNearest.m' not found.
'KNearest.m' not found.

pctRunOnAll which ('KNearest_.mexw32')
'KNearest_.mexw32' not found.
'KNearest_.mexw32' not found.
'KNearest_.mexw32' not found.
```

after cd \LAB-07\untitled+cv

```
 pctRunOnAll which ('KNearest.m')
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest.m
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest.m  % cv.KNearest constructor
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest.m

>> pctRunOnAll which ('KNearest_.mexw32')
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest_.mexw32
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest_.mexw32
\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv\KNearest_.mexw32
```

I ran and FileDependecies, but the same result.

I do not know this is related or not, I display during the execution of the program **classifiers** 
after training and before parfor

```
classifiers = 

  cv.KNearest handle
  Package: cv

  Properties:
              id: 5
            MaxK: 1
        VarCount: 128
     SampleCount: 9162
    IsRegression: 0

  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Within parfor before classifiers.predict

```
classifiers = 

  cv.KNearest handle
  Package: cv

  Properties:
    id: 5
```

---

I tested the file cvtColor.mexw32. I left in a folder only 2 files cvtColor.mexw32 and vl_sift

```
parfor i=1:2
 im1=imread('Copy_of_start40.png');
 im_vl = im2single(rgb2gray(im1));
 desc=vl_sift(im_vl);
 im1 = cvtColor(im1,'RGB2GRAY');
end
```

The same error, and vl_sift work, cvtColor  no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the worker machines can see the code in your shared filesystem, you should not need `FileDependencies` or `PathDependencies` at all. It looks like you're using Windows. It seems to me that the most likely problem is file permissions. MDCS workers running under a jobmanager on Windows by default run not using your own account (they run using the "LocalSystem" account I think), and so may well simply not have access to files on a shared filesystem. You could try making sure your code is world-readable.

Otherwise, you can add the files to the pool by using something like

```
matlabpool('addfiledependencies', {'\\LAB-07\untitled\+cv'})
```

Note that MATLAB interprets directories with a `+` in as defining "packages", not sure if this is intentional in your case.

**EDIT**

Ah, re-reading your original post, and your comments below - I suspect the problem is that the workers cannot see the libraries on which your MEX file depends. (That's what the "Invalid MEX-file" message is indicating). You could use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to work out what are the dependencies of your MEX file, and make sure they're available on the workers (I think they need to be on `%PATH%`, or in the current directory).

Comment: Yes, I run mdcs service using my own account. Could it be that for parfor loop mex files must be compiled with special rules? vl_sift.mexw32 already been compiled by developers,but mex opencv I compiled using Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

Comment: Oh, Edric, big thank you! I almost solved my problem. Please read the answer below, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Edric thanks. There was a problem in the PATH for parfor. With http://www.dependencywalker.com/ looked missing files and put them in a folder +cv. Only this method works in parfor.

But **predict** in parfor gives an error

```
PredictClasses = classifiers.predict(descr');

??? Error using ==> parallel_function at 598
Error in ==> KNearest>KNearest.find_nearest at 173
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.

What() is:..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\knearest.cpp:365: error: (-2) The search
tree must be constructed first using train method
```

I solved this problem by calling each time within parfor **train**

```
classifiers = cv.KNearest
classifiers.train(Descriptors',Labels','MaxK',1)
```

But it's an ugly solution :)

Comment: Perhaps it's enough to do the `train` piece inside an `spmd` block before your `parfor` loop? That ensures each worker MATLAB executes that stuff exactly once.